# Remote carriage return if there is only one column

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed

A proprietary command similar to "df" returns me this  :

```
FOO_vol6        1714236984   1685700840     28536144   98%    /root_vdm_10/FOO_vol6
FOO_vol4         253851840     64818424    189033416   26%    /root_vdm_10/FOO_vol4
FOO_vol0         827269560    404664536    422605024   49%    /root_vdm_10/FOO_vol0
FOO_vol1        2085318984   1318369688    766949296   63%    /root_vdm_10/FOO_vol1
FOO_vol3        5449936112   4883375096    566561016   90%    /root_vdm_10/FOO_vol3
fs_foobar_users
                7021452248   6879023968    142428280   98%    /root_vdm_6/users
fs_bar_foobarsources
                1280329688   1241297032     39032656   97%    /root_vdm_6/foobarsources
fs_foo_datas2  1858572248   1646175040    212397208   89%    /root_vdm_4/DATAS2
```

As you can see, if the column 1 lengh < ~ 15 characters, the numbers are on the same line, if not, they are on a second line.
I would like to have everything on the single line to process those data.

I need (perhaps with sed ou awk ?) to code something like : 
- if there is only one column, then, remove the carriage return 
- or, if the first word of the list if larger then ~ 16 characters, then remove carriage return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may do this:

```
$ your_df_cmd_here | sed -e '/\s/!N;s/\n\s*/ /'
```